# Strange indentation when printing output of subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm using this code to output the result of an `npm install`:

```
def run_command(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)    
    while True:
        output = process.stdout.readline()
        if process.poll() is not None:
            break
        if output:
            print (output.strip())

    rc = process.poll()
    return rc
```

But there is something wrong with my output (ubuntu)

[image]

It gets the indentation wrong somehow. Does somebody have an idea what goes wrong here and how to fix it?

**Edit (to answer question of @hansolo)**

When I use `print (repr(output.strip()))` I get this code:

```
b'\x1b[?25l[\x1b[90m..................\x1b[0m] | rollbackFailedOptional: \x1b[34;40mverb\x1b[0m \x1b[35mnpm-session\x1b[0m 54df17364582afa\x1b[0m\x1b[K\r[\x1b[7m \x1b[27m\x1b[90m.................\x1b[0m] | preinstall:rg_eat: \x1b[32minfo\x1b[0m \x1b[35mlifecycle\x1b[0m rg_eat@0.0.1~preinstal\x1b[0m\x1b[K\r[\x1b[7m \x1b[27m\x1b[90m.................\x1b[0m] | preinstall:rg_eat: \x1b[32minfo\x1b[0m \x1b[35mlifecycle\x1b[0m rg_eat@0.0.1~preinstal\x1b[0m\x1b[K\r[\x1b[7m \x1b[27m\x1b[90m.................\x1b[0m] | preinstall:rg_eat: \x1b[32minfo\x1b[0m \x1b[35mlifecycle\x1b[0m rg_eat@0.0.1~preinstal\x1b[0m\x1b[K\r[\x1b[7m \x1b[27m\x1b[90m.................\x1b[0m] | preinstall:rg_eat: \x1b[32minfo\x1b[0m \x1b[35mlifecycle\x1b[0m rg_eat@0.0.1~preinstal\x1b[0m\x1b[K\r[\x1b[7m \x1b[27m\x1b[90m.................\x1b[0m] | preinstall:rg_eat: \x1b[32minfo\x1b[0m \x1b[35mlifecycle\x1b[0m rg_eat@0.0.1~preinstal\x1b[0m\x1b[K\r[\x1b[7m \x1b[27m\x1b[90m.................\x1b[0m] | preinstall:rg_eat: \x1b[32minfo\x1b[0m \x1b[35mlifecycle\x1b[0m rg_eat@0.0.1~preinstal\x1b[0m\x1b[K\r[\x1b[7m \x1b[27m\x1b[90m.................\x1b[0m] | preinstall:rg_eat: \x1b[32minfo\x1b[0m \x1b[35mlifecycle\x1b[0m rg_eat@0.0.1~preinstal\x1b[0m\x1b[K\r[\x1b[7m \x1b[27m\x1b[90m.................\x1b[0m] | preinstall:rg_eat: \x1b[32minfo\x1b[0m \x1b[35mlifecycle\x1b[0m rg_eat@0.0.1~preinstal\x1b[0m\x1b[K\r[\x1b[7m \x1b[27m\x1b[90m.................\x1b[0m] | preinstall:rg_eat: \x1b[32minfo\x1b[0m \x1b[35mlifecycle\x1b[0m rg_eat@0.0.1~preinstal\x1b[0m\x1b[K\r[\x1b[7m \x1b[27m\x1b[90m.................\x1b[0m] | preinstall:rg_eat: \x1b[32minfo\x1b[0m \x1b[35mlifecycle\x1b[0m rg_eat@0.0.1~preinstal\x1b[0m\x1b[K\r[\x1b[7m \x1b[27m\x1b[90m.................\x1b[0m] | preinstall:rg_eat: \x1b[32minfo\x1b[0m \x1b[35mlifecycle\x1b[0m rg_eat@0.0.1~preinstal\x1b[0m\x1b[K\r[\x1b[7m \x1b[27m\x1b[90m.................\x1b[0m] | preinstall:rg_eat: \x1b[32minfo\x1b[0m \x1b[35mlifecycle\x1b[0m rg_eat@0.0.1~preinstal\x1b[0m\x1b[K\r[\x1b[7m \x1b[27m\x1b[90m.................\x1b[0m] | preinstall:rg_eat: \x1b[32minfo\x1b[0m \x1b[35mlifecycle\x1b[0m rg_eat@0.0.1~preinstal\x1b[0m\x1b[K\r[\x1b[7m \x1b[27m\x1b[90m.................\x1b[0m] | preinstall:rg_eat: \x1b[32minfo\x1b[0m \x1b[35mlifecycle\x1b[0m rg_eat@0.0.1~preinstal\x1b[0m\x1b[K\r[\x1b[7m \x1b[27m\x1b[90m.................\x1b[0m] / loadIdealTree:loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree: \x1b[7msill\x1b[0m \x1b[35minstall\x1b[0m loa\x1b[0m\x1b[K\r[\x1b[7m  \x1b[27m\x1b[90m...............(...)
```

Comment: Could you try `print(repr(output.strip()))` so you can see what exactly is in the line ?

Comment: @hansolo I put the output to my question

Comment: Add argument `text=True` (or `universal_newline=True` if you are on an older version of Python) to your `subprocess.Popen(...)` call. I think it will magically solve your problems.

Comment: @JohanL It\`s python 3.6, so those arguments are not valid for print

Comment: It's not for print but for `subprocess.Popen(...)` and while `text=True` is not valid `universal_newline=True`should be.